# Regular expression to match a Nth Word in a line

Tags: regex

Consider the below example lines

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at usu hinc iisque voluptatibus, an duo propriae definitionem. 
Per ad semper accusam blandit, eros maiestatis mei et. 
Ut mei vocibus indoctum. 
Et enim stet duo, wisi vivendo quo ad, cu nec adhuc diceret.
```

I want to select only the second word of each line. So what would be the Regulare expression for it. From the above example i would be expecting "ipsum", "ad", "mei" and "enim" words to be returned by the regular expression.

Comment: /^\w+\s+(\w+)/ with multi-line options enabled

Comment: and what's your effort into it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun your Regex works when i tested in https://www.regex101.com/ but it does not work in Notepad++

Answer (score -1):

this problem could be resolved by regex expression with sample perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Reading input line to match and output the second word of each line
while(<>){
    print "$2\n" if $_ =~ m/\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+).*/g
}
```

The results:

### perl pattern.pl < text

```
ipsum
ad
mei
enim
```

Actually,to split each line and get it easier.

Comment: i am looking for regular expression to be used in Notepad++. This is not useful

Comment: why not use vim ? it could select  the columns